# Get Json/GeoJson data of a structure

Tags: arcgis

I'm doing a project drawing 3D models using ArcgisJS. I want to ask that is there any web or tools that can help to get Json/GeoJson data such as coordinates of a point, line, surface or polygon of a structure (like maybe buildings).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So more information on how you are storing and serving this data to the client would have been useful. For 2D map/feature services, the query end point from the ArcGIS REST API, gives you the option to specify an output format f=html|JSON|GeoJSON

[ArcGIS REST API query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-map-service-layer-.htm)